# What is bass and melody in music?

Tags: guitar, theory

In guitar what strings provide bass and what string provide melody? What is the difference between bass and melody in song? How it is played in guitar?

If play song in acoustic, do I use the 654 string as bass and 321 as melody strings or I can use any string as bass root note?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to play?

Answer (score 3):

This question is missing a lot of context. It may be that there is no difference, or it may be that the bass line is played on a bass guitar, or there may be the root note of the chord (which may or may not be 'bass') played on any string (although realistically strings 1 to 4 in order to have two other notes of the chord on strings 5 and 6)

There is no rule on what strings are bass and what are melody, though. Bass is just typically the low end of the frequency range, and treble is the higher end. Melody can be anywhere.

A guitar has 6 strings, any of which may play part of a chord or be part of a melody.

In a typical guitar band, you could expect the following:

- lead guitar: plays the melody
- rhythm guitar: plays chords, and sometimes harmonies
- bass guitar: plays bass lines
- drums: drumming :-)
- and a singer or two

For that type of band the separation is obvious, but for single guitar the question may not apply at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is not always a bass line. There is not always a melody. When there is a bass line, it could be played on **any** strings of a guitar. When there is a melody, it could also be played on **any** strings of a guitar.

Sometimes only one string is used at a time and only one note is being played. In that case the one could could be both the bass and melody at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only the one guitar,the lowest note of the chord is going to be the 'bass' note.Generally it's going to be the 6th or 5th strings, for most keys, but when in D, the lowest note played on guitar is the 4th string open.So, as a basic premise, the bottom 3 strings.

Melody is something quite different, and although often played on the top three,is sometimes played on any strings that the player wants to use. Obviously, if playing a bass line and melody, the bass is as in my first paragraph, and the tune on strings 1,2,3 and 4.The bass part is often played using the thumb, for a softer sound, whilst the fingers will play the melody.